# write_xlsx function in R path argument

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx

I have a script in R that does some calculations.At the end the results are stored in a data frame like this one.

```
n= 10
x= rnorm(n)
t = seq(1:n)
d = data.frame(t,x);d
```

I want to send this script to many people which some of have Mac others have windows and some of them linux, run the script and the output to be a xlsx format file in their desktop.I know how to do it with the function `write_xlsx()` from `writexl` library to my own desktop.But how anyone can run the script and the xlsx file to be exported in their desktop ?

Might be something like :

```
write_xlsx(d,path = "my question")
```

but I don't know how.Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using [writexl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/writexl/index.html) package:

```
library("writexl")
write_xlsx(d,"path/name.xlsx")
```

Comment: If I run your code R reports an error ```[ERROR] workbook_close(): Error creating 'path/name.xlsx'. System error = No such file or directory
Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'Error creating output xlsx file. Usually a permissions error.'```

Comment: I expect @GastonAlex expected you to replace `path` with the actual path to your file.  It's unlikely you have a fiolder called `path` in your current working directory! :=)

Comment: `library("writexl")`
`write_xlsx(d,"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\R\\name.xlsx")`

Comment: Or you can just write like this : `library("writexl")`  
`write_xlsx(d,"name.xlsx")` and output file will be in the same folder as directory of R files

Comment: Run `install.packages("writexl")` First, if you have not installed it

Comment: i find it thank you both and gaston alex  for his clear answer , it helped a lot.